# How to force "invalid" Typescript to compile straight into JS?

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript

I am writing a plugin for [Nativescript](http://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins), in TS. I am following [this](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/using-native-libraries-in-nativescript/) guide to reference an android java SDK that I want to use. Essentially, to target a library's platform specific API's, you have to call them relative to their gradle import values - like so.

In my TS, I have the following line:

```
var mClient = new com.Microsoft.azure.MobileServiceClient();
```

which I believe should be fine, despite the errors, but unfortunately, it is causing `tsc` to fail -

> nsAzure.android.ts(7,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'com'

How can I get this to transpile literally into js and continue with the build and ideally not spit errors or warnings into my log?

Comment: You can try "var com = window["com"];"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just want to silence the error:

```
declare var com: any;
var mClient = new com.Microsoft.azure.MobileServiceClient();
```

Ideally you would get a .d.ts file that described `com` though.

Comment: Is there a lightweight `.d.ts` file I could make to silence the error? I don't really like the idea of changing the code in my file just to silence the compiler, but I am not sure how I would describe com in a definition file, as it is referencing a java api?

Comment: You can put `declare var com: any;` in a .d.ts file, e.g. myTypes.d.ts, and then reference it in the .ts file with `/// <reference path="myTypes.d.ts" />`. I don't really know anything about NativeScript but if you're coding this using TypeScript, the API can definitely be modeled in a .d.ts file for real and then you'd actually benefit from TypeScript's type-checking.  The TypeScript handbook has a [guide to writing .d.ts files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html)